# Pspice simulation window not there?

Tags: matlab, circuit

For some reason I don't have the **File Edit Trace Plot View Tools Window Help** options when I run the simulation, where is the option to reset it?

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but is there something like `new` or `open` under file? That may provide what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick fix, you can use Alt+F, Alt+T ... Alt+(First letter of command menu option you want to run)

Comment: It showed me the options, I guess this method works for now. If you find a way get the menu to show, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Try pressing F9, 
or when you press Alt+F the menu bar appears right click on the menu bar to check if there is an option to keep that Visible.

Comment: ( Shift + F12 ) gave me back the menu. YES! Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the ALT+ suggestion, from which SHIFT+F12 helped me get the menu back. Particularly, View->Toolbars kind of tricks...

Answer (score 0):

If the file, trace,plot, edit etc buttons are not showing it means u have alternated the display ,same problem occurs to me, so to solve that u just have do this.

I will tell u two ways but for many ppl 1st one not worked so the 2nd pls see.

1.press alt+12, if u gain the previous interface then it's great if not pls go through the 2 way below

Alt+o, then click cutomize , then u will see a interface contains of toolbars, commands, and keyboard. Go to keyboard then in "select a command' u have to scroll down and find the key called alternative display then if u click alternative display it shows the shortcut key shift+f12  but for some reasons mine not working so just change the shortcut key into ur desired key like I gave alt + l, then ok, then do alt+l or the key u gave and it will work.
Thanks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).